# Conda - "PackagesNotFoundError" unknown channels: pypi_0, py37, py37_cu102, py3.7_cuda10.2_cudnn7.6.5_0

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to create a conda env from a requirements.txt and I'm getting this error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - humanize==3.2.0=pypi_0
  - torchaudio==0.8.0=py37
  - click==7.1.2=pypi_0
  - deprecated==1.2.12=pypi_0
  - torchvision==0.9.0=py37_cu102
  - wrapt==1.12.1=pypi_0
  - simpleitk==1.2.4=pypi_0
  - dominate==2.6.0=pypi_0
  - nibabel==3.2.1=pypi_0
  - einops==0.3.0=pypi_0
  - pytorch==1.8.0=py3.7_cuda10.2_cudnn7.6.5_0
  - scipy==1.6.1=pypi_0
```

Here are my current channels in Conda:

```
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pypi/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pypi/noarch
```

Is anyone familiar what those channels are? I tried adding them via `conda config --append channels <channel name>`, but it couldn't identify them and I had to remove them, because conda install breaks if it can't identify a listed channel.

Comment: Try exporting with `conda env export` instead. The `conda list --export` format is not compatible Pip-installed packages (i.e., those with `pypi` in their build string).